# Ext.window override destroy in child class on close button of window in parent class

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have a ext.window in my code which has the default save and close button. On close button click I am hiding the window:

```
Ext.define('MyPack.template.TemplateWindow', {
extend : 'Ext.Window',

id: 'templateEditorWindow',
closeAction: 'hide',
autoScroll: false,

createTemplateEditor : function() {
 // some code
},

initComponent : function() {

this.createTemplateEditor();

Ext.applyIf(this, {
    layout      : 'border',
    modal       : true
});

this.items = [ this.templateEditor ];
this.buttons = [
    { text     : '#{msgs.button_save}',
      window   : this,
      handler  : function () {
        if(this.window.templateEditor.save()) {
          this.window.hide();
        }
      }
    },
    { text     : '#{msgs.button_close}',
      cls : 'secondaryBtn',
      window   : this,
      handler  : function( ){
        this.window.hide();
      }
    }
];

this.callParent(arguments);
}, 

});
```

I have one another window which is extending above window.

```
Ext.define('MyPack.template.RestfulTemplateWindow', {
    extend : 'MyPack.template.TemplateWindow',

    createTemplateEditor : function() {
      // some code
    }
});
```

I am creating this child class. The window is created properly. But I want to override handler function of close button. On close it should destroy.

How can I override it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a [closeAction](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.3/#!/api/Ext.window.Window-cfg-closeAction) on a window

> **closeAction** : String The action to take when the close header tool is
>   clicked:
>
> `destroy` :
>   remove the window from the DOM and destroy it and all descendant
>   Components. The window will not be available to be redisplayed via the
>   show method.
>
> `hide` :
>   hide the window by setting visibility to hidden and applying negative
>   offsets. The window will be available to be redisplayed via the show
>   method. Note: This behavior has changed! setting does affect the close
>   method which will invoke the approriate closeAction.
>
> `Defaults to: 'destroy'`

So there is no need to override anything.

**Edit >> Remember to call close() not hide()!**

```
{ 
  text     : '#{msgs.button_save}',
  window   : this,
  handler  : function () {
    if(this.window.templateEditor.save()) {
      this.window.close(); // call close!
    }
  }
},
{ text     : '#{msgs.button_close}',
  cls : 'secondaryBtn',
  window   : this,
  handler  : function( ){
    this.window.close(); // call close!
  }
}
```

**Edit**

Disclaimer: the following way is just a workaround

```
Ext.define('MyPack.template.RestfulTemplateWindow', {
    extend : 'MyPack.template.TemplateWindow',
    closeAction: 'destroy', // redefine th close action
    initComponent: function() {
      // all values set would be overrided by the parent
      this.callParent(arguments);
      // identify the buttons somehow
      this.on('beforehide',function(w){w.close();return false;},this);
    }
});
```

Comment: I have defined closeAction on child window. But still it is not destroyed. Parent class has hide on closeAction. How can I override that? I can not change parent class code.

Comment: @CODEFISH which version of ExtJS do you use?

Comment: @CODEFISH You are calling `hide()` in your demo code! Remember to change this to `close()`!

Comment: MyPack.template.TemplateWindow is the parent class which I can not change. I am creating MyPack.template.RestfulTemplateWindow which is the child class extending parent class. Button and handlers handlers are defined in parent class. I can not change them. I need to override them in child class.

Comment: Version is Ext JS 4.1.0

Comment: @CODEFISH It is not intended that `hide()` is called on a window, that is why sencha introduced the `closeAction` property. So you should always call `close()` and not `hide()`. Otherwise you have a design problem...

Comment: Is there any way around for now this because really I can't change the code. I have to convince some people.

Comment: @CODEFISH The other design error is that you set properties in your `initComponent` without checking for existing properties, which causes a dump override of any configured property (this can be done while creating or while extending!)